# How do I parse this nested JSON object?

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I have a data set which is in data format and looks like this:

```
[{'session_id': ['X061RFWB06K9V'],
  'unix_timestamp': [1442503708],
  'cities': ['New York NY, Newark NJ'],
  'user': [[{'user_id': 2024,
     'joining_date': '2015-03-22',
     'country': 'UK'}]]},
 {'session_id': ['5AZ2X2A9BHH5U'],
  'unix_timestamp': [1441353991],
  'cities': ['New York NY, Jersey City NJ, Philadelphia PA'],
  'user': [[{'user_id': 2853,
     'joining_date': '2015-03-28',
     'country': 'DE'}]]},
 {'session_id': ['SHTB4IYAX4PX6'],
  'unix_timestamp': [1440843490],
  'cities': ['San Antonio TX'],
  'user': [[{'user_id': 10958,
     'joining_date': '2015-03-06',
     'country': 'UK'}]]}
```

I am using pandas and processing it and when i use read_json, I get the following:

```
          cities                  session_id    unix_timestamp                  user
0   [New York NY, Newark NJ]    [X061RFWB06K9V] [1442503708]    [[{'user_id': 2024, 'joining_date': '2015-03-2...
1   [New York NY, Jersey City NJ, Philadelphia PA]  [5AZ2X2A9BHH5U] [1441353991]    [[{'user_id': 2853, 'joining_date': '2015-03-2...
2   [San Antonio TX]    [SHTB4IYAX4PX6] [1440843490]    [[{'user_id': 10958, 'joining_date': '2015-03-...
```

How do I process this data so that its in a better format?
Here is the data definition:

Columns:

- `session_id`: session id.
- `unix_timestamp`: unix timestamp of session start time
- `cities`: the unique cities which were searched within the same session
- `user`:

  - `user_id`: the id of the user
  - `joining_date`: when the user created the account
  - `country`: where the user is based

I tried using json_normalize but keep getting error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'

and also different types of error. Kindly help

Comment: I am a bit confused. Better than what? Is the problem that you want rows and columns when the input is hierarchical / tree shaped?

Comment: this is my first time working on JSON. I am used to working with neatly formated dataframes. How can I use this data and perform analysis. How do I parse "user" column and analyze it?

Comment: I really dont understand waht you mean by tree and rectangular shape. Can you please point me to some resources on this? I will be grateful

Comment: The general answer is it depends on the use you need to put it to. You need to decide a mapping between tree-shaped data and rectangular-shaped output (guessing given your neatly-shaped dataframes comment). In this case the hierarchy is only one deep, so you could probably do something simple like write a short function to put the attributes of the user at the same level as the rest. Then you should get a neater dataframe / rectangle.

Comment: ah okk, got it. Thanks

Comment: So `json_normalize()` is a pandas flattening function (turns tree-shaped data into rectanges/dataframes) so you weren't far off. 

The error may be caused by the unix_timestamp entry being a list of integers, rather than a dictionary or list of dictionaries. See

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012928/skipping-attribute-error-while-importing-twitter-data-into-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function that completely flattens it out, then reconstruct your dataframe:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

jsonData = [{'session_id': ['X061RFWB06K9V'],
  'unix_timestamp': [1442503708],
  'cities': ['New York NY, Newark NJ'],
  'user': [[{'user_id': 2024,
     'joining_date': '2015-03-22',
     'country': 'UK'}]]},
 {'session_id': ['5AZ2X2A9BHH5U'],
  'unix_timestamp': [1441353991],
  'cities': ['New York NY, Jersey City NJ, Philadelphia PA'],
  'user': [[{'user_id': 2853,
     'joining_date': '2015-03-28',
     'country': 'DE'}]]},
 {'session_id': ['SHTB4IYAX4PX6'],
  'unix_timestamp': [1440843490],
  'cities': ['San Antonio TX'],
  'user': [[{'user_id': 10958,
     'joining_date': '2015-03-06',
     'country': 'UK'}]]} ]



def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out

flat = flatten_json(jsonData)


results = pd.DataFrame()
columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    row_idx = re.findall(r'(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    column = item.replace(row_idx+'_', '',1)
    column = column.replace('_0', '')
    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

# If you don't want to expand/split the `cities` column, remove line below
results = results.join(results['cities'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('cities_').fillna(np.nan))

print (results)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
      session_id  unix_timestamp                                        cities  user_user_id user_joining_date user_country        cities_0         cities_1          cities_2
0  X061RFWB06K9V    1.442504e+09                        New York NY, Newark NJ        2024.0        2015-03-22           UK     New York NY        Newark NJ               NaN
1  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U    1.441354e+09  New York NY, Jersey City NJ, Philadelphia PA        2853.0        2015-03-28           DE     New York NY   Jersey City NJ   Philadelphia PA
2  SHTB4IYAX4PX6    1.440843e+09                                San Antonio TX       10958.0        2015-03-06           UK  San Antonio TX              NaN               NaN
```